# Custom Tab Indicator(With Arrow down like Indicator)

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs, indicator, pagerslidingtabstrip

[image]

Is there a wat to make a indicator like this?
it has some pointed arrow down like in the selected item?

Answer (score 21):

The only solution I could find is to grab the source code of the original `TabLayout` and customize it, according your needs.

In fact, all you need to do to get this custom pointing arrow is to override `SlidingTabStrip`'s `void draw(Canvas canvas)` method. Unfortunately, `SlidingTabStrip` is `private` inner class inside `TabLayout`.

[image]

Luckily, all support library code is open, so we can create our own `TabLayoutWithArrow` class. I replaced the standard `void draw(Canvas canvas)` by this one to draw the arrow:

```
        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.draw(canvas);
            // i used <dimen name="pointing_arrow_size">3dp</dimen>
            int arrowSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pointing_arrow_size);

            if (mIndicatorLeft >= 0 && mIndicatorRight > mIndicatorLeft) {
                canvas.drawRect(mIndicatorLeft, getHeight() - mSelectedIndicatorHeight - arrowSize,
                        mIndicatorRight, getHeight() - arrowSize, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
                canvas.drawPath(getTrianglePath(arrowSize), mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
            }
        }

        private Path getTrianglePath(int arrowSize) {
            mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

            int leftPointX = mIndicatorLeft + (mIndicatorRight - mIndicatorLeft) / 2 - arrowSize*2;
            int rightPointX = leftPointX + arrowSize*2;
            int bottomPointX = leftPointX + arrowSize;
            int leftPointY = getHeight() - arrowSize;
            int bottomPointY = getHeight();

            Point left = new Point(leftPointX, leftPointY);
            Point right = new Point(rightPointX, leftPointY);
            Point bottom = new Point(bottomPointX, bottomPointY);

            Path path = new Path();
            path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
            path.setLastPoint(left.x, left.y);
            path.lineTo(right.x, right.y);
            path.lineTo(bottom.x, bottom.y);
            path.lineTo(left.x, left.y);
            path.close();

            return path;
        }
```

Of course, the background, the particular design of the indicator can be improved/adjust according your needs.

To make my custom `TabLayoutWithArrow`, I had to copy these files into my project:

- AnimationUtils
- TabLayout
- ThemeUtils
- ValueAnimatorCompat
- ValueAnimatorCompatImplEclairMr1
- ValueAnimatorCompatImplHoneycombMr1
- ViewUtils
- ViewUtilsLollipop

To have transparency behind the arrow, you just need to set this `Shape`-`drawable`, as a  `background` for the `TabLayoutWithArrow` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="@dimen/pointing_arrow_size">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFF00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:height="@dimen/pointing_arrow_size"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And the actual usage is:

```
<klogi.com.viewpagerwithdifferentmenu.CustomTabLayout.TabLayoutWithArrow
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_layout_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I've uploaded the whole project (the TabLayoutWithArrow + one-page app which is using it) to my dropbox - [feel free to check it out](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bid2s0k9r3daigv/CustomTabLayoutApp.zip?dl=0).

I hope, it helps

Comment: It is working fine, how can we increase height of indicator?

Comment: Did u get a way to revert the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

now it doesn't work, tintmanager class is removed from support library 23.2.0 , I managed same functionality by changing background drawable at runtime inside for loop detecting clicked position , PS : check this question and answer I am  using same library  : https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/issues/141

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for anyone requiring an upward triangle using @Konstantin Loginov code

```
private Path getTrianglePath(int arrowSize) {

        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        int leftPointX = mIndicatorLeft + (mIndicatorRight - mIndicatorLeft) / 2 - arrowSize * 1 / 2;
        int mTopX = leftPointX + arrowSize;
        int mTopY = getHeight() - arrowSize;
        int rightPointX = leftPointX + arrowSize * 2;

        int leftPointY = getHeight();

        Point left = new Point(leftPointX, leftPointY);
        Point right = new Point(rightPointX, leftPointY);
        Point bottom = new Point(mTopX, mTopY);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.setLastPoint(left.x, left.y);
        path.lineTo(right.x, right.y);
        path.lineTo(bottom.x, bottom.y);
        path.lineTo(left.x, left.y);
        path.close();

        return path;
    }
```