# How to create down arrow indicator with left and right border using xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I want to make a shape for my view like this one.

[image]

Is there any way to do that with xml?
Thanks

Comment: For what purpose you need that?

Comment: You can try to use with nine-patch image background.

Comment: I want to create a slider with view pager and the selected tab will indicate to another view. The down arrow will indicate the enabled view and the rest of the line will spread over the disabled views and want to create with xml.

Comment: I think this link will help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34432781/7806873

Comment: Thanks, but my case is totally different. I just need to draw a down arrow with the top border using xml. Then I can handle the rest of the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is your custom drawable `custom_shape_down_arrow.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="250dp"
                android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#cdcdcd" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Top-Left Line -->
    <item
        android:right="150dp"
        android:bottom="18.7dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:color="#999999"
                android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Top-Right Line -->
    <item
        android:left="150dp"
        android:bottom="18.7dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:color="#999999"
                android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Left-Diagonal Line -->
    <item
        android:right="25dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="36">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:color="#999999"
                    android:width="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- Right-Diagonal Line -->
    <item
        android:left="27dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="322">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:color="#999999"
                    android:width="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**USE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="24dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <!-- Custom shape -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_custom_shape"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:background="#cdcdcd">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_shape_down_arrow">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Glad to know that. If my answer seems useful then please vote it up. Thank you...