# View Pager Indicator Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Could you please describe how can we achieve the following view pager indicator?
. Any libraries?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235068/custom-tab-indicatorwith-arrow-down-like-indicator

Comment: Thanks for the update. Haven't noticed my search

Comment: Let me try with the link you provided. Thanks !!!